# Django with and without Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am using **Django** to develop a web application on the linux server.

When it comes to deployment, a proposed way is to use **Nginx** to communicate with the client and **Django** only need to communicate with **Nginx** with **uwsgi** protocol.

The relationship is client<-Http->Nginx<-uwsgi->Django server

Latter I found that I can also push the server on public network with

`python manage.py runserver 0:0:0:0`

It seems that the Nginx can help serve the static file and media.

My question is, what is exactly the benefit of using Nginx as the middleman?

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs on runserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver):

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

Answer (score 1):

`runserver` is for debugging, in production we use gunicorn/uwsgi to boot the django app, so the question can be `Do we need Nginx if we have configured gunicorn/uwsgi for Django`, the answer is `YES`, becuase compared with gunicorn/uwsgi, Nginx has following advantages
:

- security, it can be configured to deny or allow certain ip addresses
- load balancing
- handle static files
- cache
- ...

refer to more features: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx#HTTP_proxy_and_Web_server_features